# How to get just “ids” which is not in the table “service_gos” (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I want to return only those "gos" that are not registered in the "service_gos" table by comparing "gos.id" with "service_gos.gos_id" (LARAVEL 5.6)

[goals table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DegTr.png)

[service_goals table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApOny.png)

[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3a1p.png)

[my controller function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzcmK.png)

[result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjxgS.png)

[this is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KGbt.png)

Comment: did u allow to add data into service_goals table without having relation with goals table(Does goals_id is nullable in service_goals table?)

Comment: Did you try ServiceGos::where('goals_id','!=',$goals_id_from_goals_table)->get()

Comment: Please add your code in your question and not in a image please. Thats easier to test it ourself and see what you did wrong. When adding 4 spaces before the code, stackoverflow automaticly  converts it to a code block

Comment: $goals = DB::table('goals')
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {

                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('service_goals')
                    ->whereRaw('goals.id = service_goals.goals_id');
            })
            ->select('services_id')
            ->from('service_goals')
            ->where('services_id', '=',$id)
            ->get();

Comment: i whan to return a service_id value too

Comment: Code should be included as text, not as an image of text. This is because images aren't searchable, nor are they accessible. Please [edit] your question to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the name of your tables, please change accordingly.
Try:

```
$ids = Goals::whereDoesntHave("service_goals")->pluck("id");
```